# React - How to upload an image file

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have used below code to upload an image . Just want to understand whether accessing an element through document.querySelector('img') is a good practice or not . Since i heard that you should not access dom element directly . is there a react way of doing this.

```js
previewFile() {
    var preview = document.querySelector('img'); //selects the query named img
    var file = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0]; //sames as here
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onloadend = function () {
      let pic = { "url": "", val: "0" };
      pic.url = reader.result;
      this.picArray.push(pic);
      this.setState({ pics: this.picArray });
}.bind(this);

    if (file) {
      reader.readAsDataURL(file); //reads the data as a URL
    } else {
      preview.src = "";
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `ref` is not a good way (except there's no other way).

For me, I will use onChange event to get the file.

The file can be set to state for later use (upload when click submit button) or can be directly sent to the API.

```
handleFileUpload(e) {
  const file = e.target.files[0]; // this is the file you want
  // do the rest here
}

// Component render
<input type="file" onChange={this.handleFileUpload} />
```

Comment: "I think ref is not a good way (except there's no other way)". u contradict yourself. + onChange it's an event, it's bad practice to add event listener for a non-event purposes. + if u still decided to add an event, in your callback you should address the `file.target` and not `event[0]` + in your callback the `file` is a lose type which got guarantee the bind to that actual element, while refs if 100% provides the element which you will going to work upon.

Comment: @LiorG "it's bad practice to add event listener for a non-event purposes". What does this even mean? How is it a bad practice? If the element has an event that gets triggered then it's clearly not a non-event purpose. This is exactly the way you should do it in React to avoid using refs. This is also the way `dropZone` libraries do it.

Comment: @LiorG Sorry for wrong params on the onChange event. I have fixed it.

Comment: @LiorG this is what from reactjs say about refs: `Don’t Overuse Refs
Your first inclination may be to use refs to “make things happen” in your app. If this is the case, take a moment and think more critically about where state should be owned in the component hierarchy. Often, it becomes clear that the proper place to “own” that state is at a higher level in the hierarchy.`

Answer (score 0):

You can set the ref to that element

```
render() {
    return (.... <input type='file' ref={element => this.fileInput = element)} ...
```

Then in your upload function, you can refer that element.

```
var file = this.fileInput;
```